# curl -h or curl --header not working

Tags: api, curl, box-api

i'm trying to connect ti a web api service, box-api, and following the tutorial i have to type this command to fetch a folder in the user content:

```
 curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID/items?limit=2&offset=0 -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

I tryied to connect from the command line to test the command but it keep complaining about the `-H` or the `--header` command saying that it doesn exist:

```
 -bash: -H: command not found
 -bash: --header: command not found
```

but when i type curl --help the command is in the manual:

```
 -H, --header LINE   Custom header to pass to server (H)
```

I'm confused, what should i do to connect to this site and get the JSON content? Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Your url has `&` sign. and this is making end of command on there(and running at background). You can remove this error by using quotes around. Like this

```
curl "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID/items?limit=2&offset=0" -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two problems:

1. The '&' in the middle of the URL passed to curl,
2. The order of the statements. The curl manual reports a different order for the statements. Example:

   ```
   curl -H "Authorization: Bearer AUTH_KEY" "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0/items?limit=2&offset=0"
   ```

This should be the complete solution.